# Including vars_files in playbook conditionally

Tags: ansible

I have this following play:

```
- hosts: group_of_hosts
  vars_files:
    - vars/vars1.yml
    - vars/vars2.yml
  roles:
  - { role: role1, tags: role1 }
  - { role: role2, tags: role2 }
  .
  .
  .
```

I would like to load vars/var2.yml conditionally, in my case only if particular variable, let's say `env` is defined in group_vars.
How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't include dynamically variables in `vars_files` block. You need to use `include_vars` instead.

```
- name: Conditionally include vars
  include_vars: vars/var2.yml
  when: env is defined
```